# JAXB conditioned binding

Tags: java, json, binding, jaxb, conditional-statements

i have a class like :

```
@XmlRootElement 
Class ClassA {

public long objectId;

public String status;

public String property1;

......
}
```

and i want JAXB's JSON output to be conditioned on property "status". ex:

if status != "deleted" -> bind all fields

```
{"objectId":1,"status":"new","property1":"value1","property2":"value2","prop3":"val3"....}
```

if status == "deleted" -> bind only 2 fields

```
{"objectsId":1,"status":"deleted"}
```

is that possible to do with JAXB ???
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

You could use the object graph extension we have added to MOXy in EclipseLink 2.5 to handle this use case.  You can download a nightly build from the following location:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php

**ClassA**

We will use MOXy's object graph extension to specify a subset of values that can be marshalled.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/03/moxys-object-graphs-inputoutput-partial.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/03/moxys-object-graphs-partial-models-on.html

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.*;

@XmlRootElement 
@XmlNamedObjectGraph(
    name="deleted",
    attributeNodes = { 
        @XmlNamedAttributeNode("objectId"),
        @XmlNamedAttributeNode("status")
    }
)
public class ClassA {

    public long objectId;
    public String status;
    public String property1;

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To specify MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to include a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html):

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Demo**

In the demo code below we will set the `MarshallerProperties.OBJECT_GRAPH` property to `deleted` on the `Marshaller` if the `status` on the instance of `ClassA` is equal to `deleted`.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.MarshallerProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(2);
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {ClassA.class}, properties);

        ClassA classA = new ClassA();
        classA.objectId = 1;
        classA.property1 = "value1";

        classA.status = "new";
        marshal(jc, classA);

        classA.status = "deleted";
        marshal(jc, classA);
    }

    private static void marshal(JAXBContext jc, ClassA classA) throws Exception {
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        if("deleted".equals(classA.status)) {
            marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.OBJECT_GRAPH, "deleted");
        }
        marshaller.marshal(classA, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code.  When the `status` is equal to `deleted` the `property1` value is not marshalled.

```
{
   "objectId" : 1,
   "status" : "new",
   "property1" : "value1"
}
{
   "objectId" : 1,
   "status" : "deleted"
}
```

---

I have opened the following enhancement request to make this use case even easier to handle:

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/406375

Comment: How can I make use of this if I use JAX RS with Jersey (I can't manually set properties)?